# Creating routes on Camel using domains

Tags: java, apache-camel, esb

I'm running an instance of Apache Camel in order to proxy requests to another server (depending on the URI). The server Camel is running responds through a lot of a different domains (e.g. app1.server.com, app2.server.com).

By using jetty and http4, I was able to proxy requests by doing this:

```
from("jetty://http://app.server.com:8080/app1?matchOnUriPrefix=true").to("http4://app1host:8080?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false");

from("jetty://http://app.server.com:8080/app2?matchOnUriPrefix=true").to("http4://app2host:8080?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false");
```

Is there any way which is possible to create routes according to the domain name? Something like this:

```
from("jetty://http://app1.server.com:8080?matchOnUriPrefix=true").to("http4://app1host:8080?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false");

from("jetty://http://app2.server.com:8080?matchOnUriPrefix=true").to("http4://app2host:8080?bridgeEndpoint=true&throwExceptionOnFailure=false");
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You could create Content Based Router (http://camel.apache.org/content-based-router.html) like this

```
from("jetty://http://0.0.0.0:8080")
    .choice()
        .when(header("host").contains("app1.server.com"))
            .log("app1.server.com").to(...)
        .when(header("host").contains("app2.server.com"))
            .log("app2.server.com").to(...);
```